# Set window position in Overwolf

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am developing an Overwolf app (for the Nvidia app challenge).

I am working on an in-game tips app, that will show tips relevant to what you are doing in the game. I would like a small icon to show in the **top right corner** of my screen. As far as I can see, the [Overwolf documentation](http://developers.overwolf.com/documentation/) does not show how to do this, neither do the Overwolf Dev Forums.

I have tried using CSS to put the window in the top right corner, but, while this works in Chrome, the window appears in the centre of the screen. I tried using "start_position" in the json, but it isn't working. I think that I have done something wrong with the json. If this is so, I have included the manifest.json here (in this case, the window I want to position is "MainWindow").

```
{
    "manifest_version": 1,
    "type": "WebApp",
    "permissions": ["GameInfo"],
    "meta": {
        "name": "Robocraft",
        "version": "0.1.6",
        "minimum-overwolf-version":"0.77.10",
        "author": "barndawg",
        "icon": "assets/images/Robocraft.png",
        "icon_gray": "assets/images/RobocraftGrey.png",
        "description": "Placeholder"
    },
    "data": {
        "start_window": "MainWindow",
        "windows": {
            "MainWindow": {
                "file": "index.html",
                "transparent": true,
                "resizable": false,
                "start_position": {"Top": 100, "Left": 300},
                "size": {"width": 100, "height": 100},
                "min_size": {"width": 100, "height": 100},
                "max_size": {"width": 100, "height": 100},
            }
        }
    } 
 }
```

So, my question is: how can I position an Overwolf window in the top right corner of my screen, if positioning it through the CSS does not work?

Comment: The JSON you've posted isn't valid. Try removing the comma after the "max-size" property. CSS is case insensitive, but you might try making the "top" and "left" properties all lower-case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, the JSON you've posted isn't valid. Try removing the superfluous comma after the `max-size` property. Also, although CSS is case insensitive, it may be worth defining the `top` and `left` properties as all lower-case.

Finally, I did a little bit of digging and found [this post](http://forums.overwolf.com/index.php?/topic/4228-manifests-start-position-doesnt-seems-to-work/) on the overwolf forums which suggests that there was a bug with this functionality which they were investigating back in February. If the steps outlined above don't work, I would suggest you post a follow-up on that thread and ask whether the issue was resolved.

Comment: Thanks! I've fixed the JSON, but I think there's still a bug in Overwolf. I posted a follow-up to that thread.

Comment: I fixed it. It turns out that there was no bug. I ended up using the "changePosition()" function in my JavaScript.